# Strong convergence in $L^2$ and $H^1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We have the following boundary problem $a > 0$; $\Omega$ is a bounded domain of $\mathbb R^{n}$ with smooth boundary and $g \in L^2(\Omega)$:

$$-a \Delta u^{a} + u^{a} = g, \text { in } \Omega$$
$$u^{a} = 0 \text{ on } \partial\Omega$$

1. Prove that $u^{a}$ converges to $g$ in $L^2(\Omega)$  (Hint: start proving a weak convergence).
2. Assume that g $\in H^1$. Find a necessary and sufficient condition on g such that $u^a$ converges strongly to g in $H^{1}(\Omega)$.

For the first question I considered $\int_{\Omega} \|u^{a} - g\|^2 d\Omega = {a}^2 \int_{\Omega} \|\Delta u^{a}\|^2 d\Omega$  but I don't see a way to make the RHS decreasing to zero.
For the second question I have the bilinear form, v being a test function, $v \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ 
$$\|B(u,v)\| = a \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \nabla v d\Omega + \int_{\Omega} u v d\Omega = \int_{\Omega} f v d\Omega$$
$$ \|B(u,v)\| ≤ \max(1, a) (||\nabla u||_{L^2} ||\nabla v||_{L^2} + ||u||_{L^2}||v||_{L^2})$$ It seems to me that I can use Lax-Milgram theorem which I am not entirely familiar with. However I don't understand why g being in $H^1$ is helpful.

Comment: $a\to 0$ or $a\to \infty$?

Comment: Nope only a > 0

Comment: So when you say $u^a$ converges to $g$, what is that convergent?